# How to correctly receive an array of data in input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I have an edit form, where I have an input that I'm sending an array of data through.

However, in the edit form, even though the input is returning me an array of data to edit, they are as a single value.

That is, if I remove a data returned in this input, all are removed. Also, the names in the input are all pasted together.]

What I'd like to try if it's possible is to return the data this way in the edit form:

[image: Image of form]

And from that, I could remove the name "Melissa" and submit the form again. Through autocomplete, the user should be able to search for another name to replace "Melissa", without changing the values ​​that are already present.

But I'm getting the data this way:

[image]

I created a Codesandbox of how I'm doing it in my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-ace-9wbz44?file=/src/App.tsx

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use `testValue` as the default options for your Autocomplete component.

Remove `value={field.value}`

Match `testValue`'s type to `studentOptions`'s type

```
const testValue = [
  {
    value: "João Lima",
    label: "João Lima"
  },
  {
    value: "Ana Clara",
    label: "Ana Clara"
  }
];
```

Change `result` to `result={field.value ?? testValue}`.

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-euler-0gt9c9?file=/src/App.tsx